# Flutter change FlatButton textColor

Tags: flutter, dart

in flutter and my application i'm trying to change some `FlatButton` text colors without using `ThemeData`, because in some part of application i want to have button with white text color or red,
how can i set this text colors normally?

for example:

```
FlatButton(
    color: Colors.black,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    child: Text(
      'login'
    ),
    onPressed: () {}
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0))),

FlatButton(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    textColor: Colors.red,
    child: Text(
      'login'
    ),
    onPressed: () {}
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0))),    

FlatButton(
    color: Colors.white,
    textColor: Colors.green,
    child: Text(
      'login'
    ),
    onPressed: () {}
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0))),
```

Comment: *"how can i set this text colors normally?"* - you already did it: `color: Colors.yellow,
    textColor: Colors.red,`

Comment: @pskink yes, but it didn't work and all of button's textColors are black

Comment: `FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  textColor: Colors.red,
  child: Text('foo', textScaleFactor: 3.0,),
),` works just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `TextStyle` using inside the `Text` widget like below :

```
FlatButton(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    child: Text(
      'login',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
    ),
    onPressed: () {}
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0))),
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the `textColor` property isn't working for you, but try giving the child `text` widget `style` as I have shown below it will work.

```
FlatButton(
      color: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.green,
      child: Text("This is a flatButton",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, //This will do the work
          )),
      onPressed: () {},
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
    ),
```